# concat in sql rounding the float columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to concatenate between several fields (text and numeric) and It must be accurate. Some of the fields are originally Numeric(19,6) and I need it to be with only 2 digits after the decimal point.

I'm using the following queries and if I run no. 1 I get in the CONCAT_AMOUNT a rounded numbers like so: 38156.738156.7 and in no. 2 I get it correct - 476.47476.47.

Why is it happening and how can I solve this with minimum functions?

```
SELECT 
    38156.650000 AS AMOUNT, 
    CAST(38156.650000 as float), 
    CONCAT(cast(38156.650000 as float), 
           cast(38156.650000 as float)) AS CONCAT_AMOUNT

SELECT 
    467.47 AS AMOUNT, 
    CAST(467.47 as float), 
    CONCAT(cast(467.47 as float), 
           cast(467.47 as float)) AS CONCAT_AMOUNT
```

Comment: Have you tried not using float? That's not supposed to be used for accurate numbers -- and for rounding, you'll need to use round

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so SQL Server makes some assumptions when converting floating point values to strings.  That shouldn't be surprising.  The database cannot print out an *infinite* number of places after the decimal point.

So, two easy choices:  convert to decimal or use `str()`:

```
select concat(cast(38156.650000 as decimal(10, 2)) . . .
```

or

```
select concat(str(38156.650000, 10, 2) . . .
```

Note:  the first version is SQL standard and should work in any database.