# Create hashvalue of all column except primary key - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query for MySQL to get hashvalue of table columns except for the primary key.

I need to do same thing for SQL Server so far I have tried hashbytes but the result is not looking right.

The query for MySQL I'm using to create hash values for all columns except primary key is this

```
SELECT MD5(CONCAT(ISNULL(COLUMN1,''),ISNULL(COLUMN2,''),ISNULL(COLUMN3,''))) as HASHVALUE, PRIMARYKEY FROM TABLE_NAME1
```

And what I have tried with SQL so far is this..

```
SELECT HashBytes('MD5', COLUMN1) AS HASHVALUE , PRIMARYKEY FROM TABLE_NAME1
```

Result from mysql >

```
|HASHVALUE                        | Primary |   
|:------------------------------- |:-------:|                   
|7a16284f87ab262f0047f4c0b4e50b2c | 0       |
|d41b398c603086da409e87ee35824cf6 | 2       |
|c0e7b9b9c29703282a9f192a4c0aead9 | 6       |
|ce13595c356a0a373140f3fda1eb5fb3 | 7       |
```

Result from SQL >

```
| HASHVALUE     | PRIMARY |
| ----------    | ------- |
|ã $t  J ¦OlU   | 1       |
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags to only include the RDBMS you want your solution in.

Comment: @DaleK I will be careful next time! thankyou.

Comment: It would also help us if you gave us some source data and associated resulting hash from MySql, so we could be sure Sql Server was creating the **exact** same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Server result is still in binary. You must convert to a string:

```
LOWER(CONVERT(varchar(32), HashBytes('MD5', COLUMN1), 2))
```

See it here to prove you get the same results, even after combining columns:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b11c422fe9236043ba5edbeb7d97043d

You can use the menu at the top of the linked page to switch between MySql and SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
What should I do if I have int datatype? I was adding source data in question and your reply showed up. 

I have added details here.. 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f39a0b860e81b73710baf2b9d867557d

Comment: @nTlearn Use `CONCAT` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c025b59bccd8607eedcd953861b2ddb

Comment: @Charlieface following up on this, does this is convert float datatype to int before converting into a hash? I m not getting the hash I m supposed to get.

Comment: You need to check if it's formatting it the same.

Comment: @Charlieface  I saw this post "SQL Server makes some assumptions when converting floating-point values to strings."
[hashvalue mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695204/concat-in-sql-rounding-the-float-columns)

How do I overcome this? I m creating query dynamically (entering column names) so I cant really enter the float datatype column name and cast it to int.. I m confused.

Comment: You can't expect SQL Server to just "do the right thing" if you don't tell it. You will need to dynamically give a `CONVERT` style number to match what you need